# Android & Google App engine Federated Login

Tags: android, google-app-engine, authentication, openid

i'm trying to create an Android app using App Engine backend with Federated Login authentication.

I read this post http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Authenticating-against-App-Engine-from-an-Android-app but it seams it only works with Google Accounts.
I also tried LeanEngine (http://www.lean-engine.com) but it needs a server side library as well which is not useful because my login logic is already implemented (and difficult to change).

I need a simple way to create the login mechanism on Android. Any idea what I could use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Federated Login is web-based so you will need to use WebView in your Android app to show login & confirmation web pages inside your app.

Also, Federated Login is OpenID based so it will only work with OpenID auth providers - AFAIK out of the big guys only Google, Yahoo and MySpace support it.

Comment: Ok, so will probably have to get cookies whenever a login is made and set those cookies when i make a server request right ?

Comment: Cookies assume that you have the session support enabled: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Enabling_sessions Note that GAE sessions have problems with clients that do not honour cookies (=devices) - in this case they will create a new session (with entity in DB) for every request.

Comment: You can simulate cookies/sessions by creating your own auth token that you return on login. Client then sends this auth token (in http header) with every request. Server then checks if token is valid, otherwise returns 404. On login you invalidate (delete from DB) the auth token.